# Strange special characters appearing

Tags: python, special-characters

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-TlNEeXh6QldLT2c/edit

I am trying to have a program that will remove the special characters in the above txt.

I already have a remover like this.

```
chars = [u'\u001A', u'\u001C', u'\u001D', u'\u001E', u'\u0085'];

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

ifile = codecs.open(input_file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode="rb")
ofile = codecs.open(output_file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode="wb")

for line in ifile:
    for ch in chars:
        if ch in line:
            line = line.replace(ch, '')     
    ofile.write(line)

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

But it can't remove those characters in that txt. Rather, it crashes. What should I do?

Comment: The Error you got is an indentation error. To put the second ForLoop within the first one you have to indent it.

Comment: @user3433065 In the file I indented it correctly. I just mistakenly didn't indent when I pasted it to stackoverflow. I corrected it.

Comment: ¿What is the error trace?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with:

```
input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

ifile = codecs.open(input_file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode="rb")
ofile = codecs.open(output_file, encoding = 'utf-8', mode="wb")

for line in ifile:
    for ch in line:
        try:
            ofile.write(ch.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass     

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

As a little hint, for the code to be more pythonic look at *with* statements.

Comment: Doesn't this code include the command to erase special characters like u'\u001A', u'\u001C', u'\u001D', u'\u001E', u'\u0085'?